# how to understand the statement in SQL

Tags: t-sql, null

In some stored procedures I see the following statement in `where` clause:

```
...
where
(@val1 is null or val = @val)
```

What does it mean?

Comment: null can never equal anything so it must be checked for explicitly. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this before in a stored procedure when passing a variable that is used to filter the result set.  The `null` value signifies that the parameter should not be used as a filter.

- If `@val1` is null, then the expression is true and the results are not filtered.
- If `@val1` is not null, then the results will be filtered and the `val` column must match the parameter.